# SQL Table Relationships - Trying to Avoid Cyclical Relationships

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to manage table relationships in my database, but every option I mock up ends up creating cyclical relationships, which seem to be a big no-no. Here is my setup:

I have the **Group** table:

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | group1 |
|  2 | group2 |
+----+--------+
```

I also have a **UserToGroup** table giving users access (with varying permission level) to groups, with FKs pointing to my **Group** (many-to-one) and to my **User** table (many-to-one):

```
+----+----------+---------+---------------+
| id | group_id | user_id | permission_id |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 |             2 |
|  2 |        1 |       2 |             3 |
|  3 |        2 |       1 |             2 |
+----+----------+---------+---------------+
```

Where I get stuck is that I want to add an owner flag on each instance of the **Group** table, where creating a FK constraint would block SQL from removing the **UserToGroup** instance of a group's owner (ultimately the owner of a group cannot lose permission access to its group.

Functionally, owner permission is completely independent from the permissions granted to users (as the owner would have access to certain management pages, while permission access grants various levels of read/write), and I want to always maintain a required **UserToGroup** instance in the database for the group's owner, stopping the database (through FK constraints) from the possibility of removing the owner from the *UserToGroup* table, where he manages all users for a given group.

Initially I had `Group.owner_id` pointing to the given **User**, but that only create a FK constraint for when the user is deleted.

I have also tried creating the following variations to my database, but they create cyclical relationships:

Where I created a FK in my **Group** table pointing to a **UserToGroup** instance labelling it as the owner's instance:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id |  name  | owner_user_to_group |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | group1 |                   2 |
|  2 | group2 |                   3 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Inversly, where I created an owner table that would manage the owner check between the **Group** and **UserToGroup** tables:

```
+----+----------+------------------+
| id | group_id | user_to_group_id |
+----+----------+------------------+
|  1 |        1 |                2 |
|  2 |        2 |                3 |
+----+----------+------------------+
```

But in both cases it creates a cyclical relationship with the **Group** table, where both cannot be created without each other.

Is there a way I can manage both owner and permissions separately for **Group** instances, but also create a logical relationship between both in my database so that I can use the FK constraints to avoid SQL from deleting the **UserToGroup** instance of the Group's owner?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood but are you looking for this?

If not, try to explain more simply what you need exactly and I'll try again.
[image]